# python - return the number if the file name contains only numbers

Tags: python

So I have a bunch of files with numbers and/or string. For example, file names:

```
2214
2214-hello
2214_world
1123
1124
32415
92511
2123-John
helloapple
byebanana
```

And I have a list of names on csv called ListA:

```
2214
92511
helloapple
byebanana
```

I need help to get the files that are on listA and have only digits in the name. I am aware of the isdigit() method. But I am actually passing on this file names as pattern to a directory path. My original code is like this:

```
my_files = _globrec(r'C:/Test/', '\*apple*','\*banana*')
```

So apple and banana are patterns in my files. And I want to add one more pattern after banana for digit only. Is there a way to do this?

_globrec is a recursive function and works just fine to match multiple patterns in my files. I only found this (on another post) to match multiple patterns but I am open to other options too.

```
def _globrec(path, *exts):
    dirs = [a[0] for a in os.walk(path)]
    f_filter = [d+e for d in dirs for e in exts]
    return [f for files in [glob.iglob(files) for files in f_filter] for f in files]
```

If I will print my_files, the end result should be:

```
C:/Test/2214
C:/Test/92511
C:/Test/helloapple
C:/Test/byebanana
```

Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that _globrec is a glob.glob recursive.
It's actually simple regular expressions.

[Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Then you can use

```
glob.glob('*[0-9].*')
```

Which in your case is:

```
_globrec(r'C:/Test/', '\*apple*','\*banana*', '*[0-9].*')
```

Refer the Python documentation for more info:

[glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

This one gives a better example:

[Python Module of the week: glob](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match only digits, use `'\d+'`. This is because `\d == [0-9] == [0123456789]` and `+` means to match one or more of the preceding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pattern ^[0-9]+$ to match just numbers.
^ indicates it must start with a number and $ indicates it must end with a number.

Comment: This is equivalent to \d+ as Ben suggested above.

Comment: Oops sorry hadn't seen the answer.